# tortoisesvn error: redirect cycle detected

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tortoise svn giving me “Redirect cycle detected for URL ‘domain/svn’”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524646/tortoise-svn-giving-me-redirect-cycle-detected-for-url-domain-svn)

Here's what I did (these have worked in the past):

1.Downloaded and installed TortoiseSVN

2.Created a new folder C:\phpwebsite

3.Right-clicked, chose SVN Checkout...

4.Entered the following information, clicked OK:

URL of repository: https://-svn.cvsdude.com/phpwebsite
Checkout directory: C:\phpwebsite
Checkout depth: Fully recursive
Omit externals: Unchecked
Revision: HEAD revision
5.Got TortoiseSVN error:

Redirect cycle detected for the url

Comment: that means what it says, there must be a redirect loop in the url you specified. have you tried accesing it in a web browser?

Comment: yes i tried accessing it in browser,its work fine,now what should i do for resolving this problems?

Comment: do you have any sym links in the repository that point to a parent folder of the repository?

Comment: specify what type of sym links and how can i find it.because i am new in svn.

Comment: who's maintaining the svn repository? are you doing it or is it someone else? this is an error on the server-side and if you don't have access to it you'll have to contact whoever is maintaining it. on the server there might be a symbolic link inside the repository that points to a parent directory of the repository. check vie the command line