# SVN: redirect cycle detected for url

Tags: apache, svn, suse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tortoise svn giving me “Redirect cycle detected for URL ‘domain/svn’”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524646/tortoise-svn-giving-me-redirect-cycle-detected-for-url-domain-svn)

I have a problem with apache and svn. I'll get an error when I want to check out my repository by using the adress

> https://server.de:81/repository

My svn.conf is:

```
  NameVirtualHost *:81
  <VirtualHost *:81>
          ServerName svn.server.com 
          ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/svn_error
          LogLevel warn
          CustomLog /var/log/apache2/svn_access combined
          ServerSignature On

          # SSL fÃ¼e Repos
          SSLEngine On
          SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.pem/server.LOCAL.pem
          SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.LOCAL.key
          SSLProtocol all

          <Location />
                  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
                  AuthType Basic
                  AuthBasicProvider ldap
                  AuthName "server.LOCAL"
                  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldap svn,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
                  AuthLDAPBindPassword "pw"
                  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server.local:3268/DC=server,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
                  require valid-user
          </Location>

        # repositories for Group repo1
          <Location /repo1>
                  DAV svn
                  SVNPath /srv/svn/repo1
                  require ldap-group CN=svn-repo1,OU=Svn,DC=server,DC=local
          </location>
          # repositories for Group repo2
          <Location /repo2>
                  DAV svn
                  SVNPath /srv/svn/repo2
                  require ldap-group CN=svn-repo2,OU=Svn,DC=repo2,DC=local
          </location>
</VirtualHos>
```

I can browse my repository by browser but not with tortois svn. Does anybody find the error?