# What is the cause of "svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL"?

Tags: svn, apache2, webdav, websvn

Trying to checkout from my SVN repo gives me

```
    svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL ...
```

However, it appears as if this error only occurs when I am behind some (specific) proxy server.

As discussed in other post (see [tortoise svn giving me "Redirect cycle detected for URL 'domain/svn'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524646/tortoise-svn-giving-me-redirect-cycle-detected-for-url-domain-svn) ), this error occurs if the SVN DAV is misconfigured, e.g., using SVNParentPath where one should use SVNPath. However, my configuration appears to be correct and - as far as I know - the problem only occurs when behind a proxy.

The setup of the repository is more or less standard, e.g.,

```
    ServerAlias  svn.mydomain.com
    <Location /myrepo>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/myrepo
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "mydomain svn"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/svn.mydomain.com/conf/htpasswd-myproject
        # Allow read-only access to anyone, otherwise require
        # require authentication
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(I given an answer to my own question, after using half a weekend to search for the solution):

It appears as if this error message is related to the fact that the subversion repository is located in a directory `svn/myrepo` where the directory `svn` is also listed as the DocumentRoot of the subdomain `svn.mydomain.com`. That DocumentRoot directive was not obvious to me, since the document root of the subdomain was configered in a different conf file (I am using Plesk to maintain the server).
This created some kind of ambiguity. Once I moved the document root of the subdomain to a different location, the error message went away.

The problem was hard to track down, because - as far as I know -

- The error does not appear if the repo is located at the top level of the subdomain, i.e. `<Location />` and `SVNPath /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn` in the above configuration.
- The error only shows up if the repo is accessed via a proxy.
- The clash with DocumentRoot was not so obvious, because it was a subdomain.

So to summarize: **the solution (when using Plesk)**: Change the "DocumentRoot" of the subdomain in the Plesk setup (GUI) to something different form the SVN directory. The "DocumentRoot" of www.mydomain.com is `httpdocs`. The "DocumentRoot" of svn.mydomain.com was (by default) `svn`. I changed that to `httpdocs-svn` and the problem was gone. The folder `httpdocs-svn` isn't used in my setup since everything below svn.mydomain.com is handled by DavSVN.

Comment: I'm getting this error message but it's not that solution. I have vanilla Apache2 with vanilla subversion and libapache2-svn, all installed and running and I have used SVNParentPath and created two repos in /var/lib/svn and I can browse to them in my browser (empty so far, but it works). But if I try to import or checkout from the command line to the same URI http://localhost/svn/foo I get this error about the Redirect cycle. there is positively NO Redirect directive anywhere in any file under /etc/apache2 so where is it coming from? Bear in mind this is a default install, so no manual edits.

Comment: It is a long time ago that I had this issue but as far as I remember you do not need an explicit redirect and it can happen in a default install if the SVN root directory and the web page (apache) root directory are the same. - But: I do not know if there are other configs which result in the same error message.

Comment: It turns out that it's NOT a Redirect but an Alias. For some unfathomable reason the default dav_svn.conf installed by libapache2-svn (I think) is broken, as it contains a bogus Alias /svn /var/lib/svn and you need to comment it out. Then everything works. Why this is shipped broken I cannot say.

Answer (score 28):

I was facing similar kind of error following this tutorial:
[How to Install SVN Server on Ubuntu 18.04 & 16.04 LTS](https://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-server-on-ubuntu/). Later realized, I have to delete the following line in **Step 5**

> Alias /svn /var/lib/svn

Comment: terima kasih !!

Comment: No, it is not updated, I also had this problem after following this tutorial

Comment: may be now it's in step 5

Comment: sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf

Comment: this guy deserve a coffee !

Answer (score 14):

Make sure the link you are using is the 'svn' and not the 'view' link.

i.e. [www.myrepo.com/svn/myproject/trunk](http://www.myrepo.com/svn/myproject/trunk)   ||correct
     [www.myrepo.com/view/myproject/trunk](http://www.myrepo.com/view/myproject/trunk)  ||incorrect

That should work.

Comment: I think this has been unjustly demoted. I got the exact same error message while trying to checkout viewvc web view urls. Examples http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/sandbox/ or http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/axis/axis1/java/trunk

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem is there was a non compatible settings between to configuration files on ubuntu.

I have ubuntu 18.04 and Apache2 and the lastest svnserver from ubuntu and to solve the problem of redirecting i had to remove Alias from two different configuration files: **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn** and **/etc/apache2/site-enabled/default-ssl.conf**

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn**

```
 #Alias /svn /svn_repo/svn
 <Location /myrepo>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn_repo/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /mypath/dav_svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
</Location>
```

**/etc/apache2/site-enabled/default-ssl.conf**

```
 #Alias /svn /svn_repo/svn
 <Location /myrepo>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn_repo/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /mypath/dav_svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
</Location>
```

obviusly after modification i need to restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: That's the solution! Viewing in the browser worked fine, but checking out via `svn checkout` always ended with the error `svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL ...`. Removing the `Alias /web/path /path/to/svn/repo` brought success. Now displaying via the browser works, as does checking out via the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the SVN URL which you gave during check-out. I checked various post for this problem but none of them worked for me. Below is the very simple solution that worked for me,

You need to you csvn repository using link 'http://localhost:3343/csvn/repo/list
' and copy the URL of 'Checkout command' for the repository which you want to access.

This URL you need to use in the tortoise SVN client for checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the same issue. Follow the Below steps:

Remove

```
Alias /svn /var/lib/svn` ( `# Alias /svn /var/lib/svn` ) ,
```

and

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```