# Why does Apache SVN repository list show empty?

Tags: apache, svn

I'm migrating from Visual SVN on a Windows machine to SVN served via Apache on a Linux machine.  So far mostly successfully.  I can access the repositories via `svn` on the command line from multiple machines and browse the repository contents if I put in the full URL of an individual repository into a web browser.  It also properly requires authentication.

When I go to the root directory (`/svn`) in the browser, however, I'm getting an *empty* listing of repositories.  I have found a lot of posts across the internet on the situation where the listing is blocked, i.e. you get an HTTP 403 instead of a listing, but that is *not* my case.  I'm getting a list - it just happens to be empty.  That shows in the browser as a well-formed page with nothing between the `<ul></ul>` tags that would have the contents, and it shows in the Apache logs as a successful (HTTP 200) response given.

So the question is why this happens and how to fix it?

Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.example.com
        Alias /svn /var/lib/svn
        <Location /svn>
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath "/var/lib/svn/"
                SVNListParentPath On
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "My Software Repository"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /svn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There are multiple virtual hosts on this machine.  I've shown just the section for the SVN host.

This is the HTML returned when I navigate to `svn.example.com/svn` in a browser (after authenticating):

```
<html><head><title>Collection of Repositories</title></head>
<body>
 <h2>Collection of Repositories</h2>
 <ul>
 </ul>
 <hr noshade><em>Powered by <a href="http://subversion.apache.org/">Apache Subversion</a> version 1.9.5 (r1770682).</em>
</body></html>
```

Prior to adding the `SVNListParentPath on` section, I would received instead an HTTP 403, and, to emphasize, that's the case that I see most often addressed here and elsewhere.  But that is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the line `Alias /svn /var/lib/svn` seems to have fixed the problem without causing any new issues.

I found this by accident dealing with a "redirect cycle", which is addressed by one of the answers to this other question that is otherwise unrelated: [What is the cause of "svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474825/what-is-the-cause-of-svn-e195019-redirect-cycle-detected-for-url)