# Subversion import via https not working

Tags: apache, svn

I installed Subversion on a rootserver running CentOS 6. Took me a while, but now I can access the repository using Chrome. I can add files (svn import at command line level),  but only when specifying a file:/// path for the destination, https:// giving me "svn: The project archive was moved permanently to [...]; please relocate". I didn't find a single answer helping me with that particular error / message. So I don't even know what it means, what triggers it, ...

On my client I want to use UEStudio (UltraEdit Studio) which has built-in support for Subversion. When trying to do a checkout in UEStudio using the account I created when installing Subversion on the server it tells me "unable to connect to a repository at URL [...]" and also asks for a password. I saved username and password in UEStudio and can login using the exact same credentials in Chrome. The URL UEStudio isn't able to find a repository at is the same I use to browse my repository in Chrome. I'm puzzled!

So I need help setting up Subversion and UEStudio so they finally work together. I cannot offer more details because I'm not sure which ones are necessary. I already spent a couple of hours trying to solve this so I'm not sure what counts any more.

Please feel free to ask for additional details if needed, I'm happy to help!

Comment: What Web server do you use? In case of Apache have you installed & activated the svn module? Just publishing an SVN repository via Web is not enough!

Comment: Yeah, I use Apache. And both mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.so are loaded. Is that what you mean? This is the part of the config where they are being loaded:
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Comment: What happen if you do a checkout via command-line (or e.g. a SVN client like TortoiseSVN) using the https url?

Comment: I tried with TortoiseSVN and it gives me this error: Redirect cycle detected for URL '...'. Any ideas how to find out what can cause this? I know what redirect means, I just cannot come up with a possible cause in my case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524646/tortoise-svn-giving-me-redirect-cycle-detected-for-url-domain-svn) and pointing UEStudio to the x86-version  (used x64 so far) of the Subversion client binaries helped, it works now! Also tried UEStudio again and it works as well!! So the problem was I didn't offer a project at checkout, but the parent directory (the repository itself?), as well as offering the x64 binaries to UEStuido.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, Robert!! :)